# Nancy Unable to resolve type when constructor has parameters

Tags: c#, .net, nancy

When I have the following code:

```
public class Webserver: NancyModule
{
    public Webserver()
    {
        Post[""] = _ => 200;
    }
}
```

Everything works, but when I have this

```
public class Webserver: NancyModule
{
    public Webserver(string id="")
    {
        Post[""] = _ => 200;
    }
}
```

I get 8 inner exceptions, one of which is `TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: <namespace>.Webserver`.

---

In a likely related problem, when I have the following code I get the same exception:

```
public class Webserver<T> : NancyModule
{
    public Webserver()
    {
        Post[""] = _ => 200;
    }
}
```

I have Nancy version `1.4.3` installed and Nancy.Hosting.Self version `1.4.1` installed.

Answer (score 0):

Your modules must be resolvable using the `TinyIocContainer` of the application. This means that you cannot pass primitive constructor parameters as TinyIoc will not know how to create them. Anything you pass as parameter to the module must itself be resolvable through the container.

The same thing goes for the second case. As you have made the module generic, TinyIoc will not know how to create it. You could create an abstract generic base class for your modules, but each exposed module must close this generic class.